# Resttemplate unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, resttemplate

I am trying to unit test a method which is calling a resttemplate inside. But somehow my test is not working. The method that I want to test looks so

```
public Integer createAccount(Request request) {
    final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/stubs/otl/account/create";
    return restTemplate.postForObject(uri, request, Integer.class);
}
```

My Unit tests looks so

```
@InjectMocks
AccountServiceImpl accountService;

@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${url.otl}")
private String urlOtl = "http://localhost:8080/stubs/otl/";

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void createAccountTest(){

    MockRestServiceServer mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);

    mockServer.expect(requestTo(urlOtl+"account/create"))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
            .andRespond(withSuccess("1", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    Request request = new Request();
    Integer result = accountService.createAccount(request);
    mockServer.verify();
    Assert.assertEquals("1", String.valueOf(result));
}
```

When I ran the test, I get as response

> java.lang.AssertionError: Further request(s) expected 0 out of 1 were
>   executed  at
>   org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer.verify(MockRestServiceServer.java:167)

Can somebody tell me what I am missing or doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

A `MockRestServiceServer` has a list of `expectedRequests` within it, that represent requests to the server that have been set up and are expected to be called.

`verify()` then asserts that all these expected requests have been called and hit the server.

So it seems like in your case, the `"http://localhost:8080/stubs/otl/account/create"` request is expected, but hasn't been called before the `verify()` method has been called, so `verify()` fails its assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The Reason for the above error is either the rest url is not getting hit or the result is not coming as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue recently and took me ages to figure out. I was not hitting my endpoint and you are probably doing the same. The issue is probably set up related. Maybe restTemplate hasnt been set up correctly in the test or service. Do a null check for resttemplate somewhere